# Pixelated PNG exports from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, typesetting

I am making display ads in InDesign.
The sizes are rather small (300x600, 300x250, 336x280, 720x900.

The images I placed and the text get pixelated on the PNG export.

When I export at 600 DPI and then scale down in Photoshop, the sharpness of the images is much better (but the process is incredibly more cumbersome).

Cannot / don't want to share the whole image, but my point should get across even without seeing the whole thing.

**Screenshot of the InDesign composition:**
Normal sharpness expected

[image]

**Pixelated InDesign PNG export - Anti-alias is checked:**
At 100% of the size, text and images look bad and almost garbled

[image]

**Extremely pixelated InDesign PNG export - Anti-Alias is unchecked:**
Now this is just atrocious

[image]

**Higher-resolution PNG export, scaled down in PhotoShop:**
Looks better

[image]

**How do I get the image quality seen in the last screenshot from InDesign, without having to export at 600 DPI and scaling each image down one by one in Photoshop?**